# wrong number or types of arguments in call to

Tags: c#, oracle, plsql

I have created a package successfully.
But when I try to call this on my C# program
I am getting an error:
wrong number or types of arguments in call to LOG_STATUS

LOG_STATUS is the name of the procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY ITMON.SERVERSTATUS AS  
PROCEDURE LOG_STATUS(out_RESULT OUT sys_refcursor)   
IS 
BEGIN
OPEN out_RESULT FOR
    SELECT HOSTNAME, USERS, PS_NAME 
    FROM PS_COLLECT
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
( 
        SELECT HOSTNAME, USERS, PS_NAME
        FROM PS_MASTER
        WHERE PS_MASTER.HOSTNAME = PS_COLLECT.HOSTNAME 
        AND PS_MASTER.USERS = PS_COLLECT.USERS 
        AND PS_MASTER.PS_NAME = PS_COLLECT.PS_NAME
    );
 END LOG_STATUS;  
END;
```

Here is my C# Code:

```
            OracleCommand OCom = new OracleCommand("SERVERSTATUS.LOG_STATUS", oc);
            OCom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            OCom.Parameters.Add("out_RESULT", OracleType.VarChar, 30000).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            OCom.Parameters[0].Value = sid;

            OracleDataAdapter _daGrid1 = new OracleDataAdapter(OCom);

            _daGrid1.Fill(_dsGrid);
```

Comment: The error is clear , could you share your code ?

Comment: I wonder how you pass type sys_refcursor in your C# code. The error must lay there.

Comment: how should I pass the type sys_refcursor then? I have edited my post and shared a bit of the code.

Comment: FOUND IT. should be: OCom.Parameters.Add("out_RESULT", OracleType.Cursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

Comment: Very interesting. Suggest you post it yourself as an anser and accept it.

Comment: What do you mean @hol? You suggest that I post it?

Comment: Yes, unlikely someone with the same/similar problem in future will scan through this comments but will rather look at the answers.

Comment: What @hol means is - since *you* found the answer, *you* should post your solution as an answer (below) to your own question, and then accept that answer.  This gives you the credit you deserve for **answering your own question** (oh, and +1 on the question for doing just that :-).  Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what's wrong with my code..

Should change this line:

```
OCom.Parameters.Add("out_RESULT", OracleType.VarChar, 30000).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

to

```
OCom.Parameters.Add("out_RESULT", OracleType.Cursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

Should use Cursor instead of varchar..